# emacs modify `Save file` prompt behaviour

Tags: emacs, elisp

In `emacs` I sometimes get asked if I want to save this or that file.

```
Save file /a/b/c (y, n, !, ., q, C-r, d or C-h)
```

This is a fine behavior on the overall, but I sometimes get asked this question a lot (ex. when using `magit`).

Would there be a way to either :

- add another option like "don't ask for this file and the rest of the files" this time
- add another option like "don't ask for this file and the rest of the files for the next two minutes"
- something else I haven't thought of

Comment: The first option is already offered to you by that prompt (either `!` or `q` depending on what you want to do; note that `C-h` is the "help" binding).